# develop custom package, avoid rsyncing source to the build directory

Tags: buildroot

I have custom package, where the sourcecode is directly in the package directory.
At the moment buildroot copies the sourcode to the builddirectory.

Is it possible to avoid this unnecessary overhead? The Makefile supports srcdir != builddir. 
in < 2011 buildroot it was possible to specify the SRCDIR and nothing was rsynced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not supported right now. We are working on supporting out-of-tree build on a per-package basis in order to solve this issue. A first prototype has been sent to the list some time ago, but needs more work.

Comment: do you remember the subject name? i can't find it in my archive